# Laravel 8 session not persist when redirect to the home (root) page

Tags: laravel, session, cpanel

I'm working on Laravel website, on the local environment the site works well, the issue appeared after deployment on cpanel, the process works as follows, after login successfully the user is redirected to profile page, the problem is seen when redirecting to the (root) home page, the session is not persist,

i've changed the session_drive from 'file' to 'database' however the problem not solved, also added the web middleware to web routes but not solved the problem

Comment: did you try `php artisan cache:clear` ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried cache:clear, route:clear, config:clear but no way

Comment: what is session driver?

Comment: In order to save the user opened session details i.e. account data, the laravel framework provides a set of drivers '

Comment: Could you share your code on how you are redirecting the user to homepage?

Comment: there is no redirect, it's just the homepage route name under the homepage link, and the route returns the home view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review, it turns out that the issue because i didn't add a guest middleware on the login route in the web.php file